# Is this a valid Singleton implementation?

Tags: java, jdbc, singleton, database-connection

```
package com.infoobjects.emsmaria.connection.jdbc;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.Statement;
public class JDBCConnection {
    private static Statement Singleton_stmt = null;
    private static Connection con = null;
    public static Statement getStatement() {
        Statement stmt = null;
        try {
            if (Singleton_stmt == null && con == null) {
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
                con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/EMSCMS", "root", "");
                Singleton_stmt = con.createStatement();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        return stmt;
    }   
}
```

Is this a valid singleton implementation to get statements in different classes?

Comment: Your current method (getStatement) will always return null.

Comment: `stmt` will always be null so `getStatement()` will always return null as well.

Comment: Not at all. It's riddled with flaws such as swallowing any exceptions, unnecessary casts and the concept of a "singleton statement".

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should be migrated to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

There are many, many things wrong with this code:

1. It is buggy; you are assigning to `Singleton_stmt`, and returning the unset `stmt`.
2. It ignores exceptions. Don't do that. This method should be declared to `throws SQLException`, that's the best solution – and then you do not need a try/catch at all. If you insist on this design mistake that it shouldn't, at least put in the catch block: `throw new RuntimeException("Uncaught", e);`.
3. It does not adhere to java conventions. it's `singletonStmt`, not `Singleton_stmt`.
4. SQL does not work this way; you can only use plain jane statements if you have zero variables, as in, nothing to put into the query other than a single, long, hardcoded SQL string. Something like `stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = " + username)` is a security leak that will get your server hacked in a heartbeat. The correct solution is to use a `PreparedStatement`; having a DB connection tool that only lets you use statements is dangerous and broken.
5. connections must be closed; this code doesn't ever do that, or if a caller does, this code is then permanently broken (the connection is not null, but invalid, and this code will never remake it).
6. There is no need for the `Class.forName` line; remove it. Or if you want to ensure that you get an error at compile time if the mysql jdbc driver isn't on the classpath, write `Class.forName(com.mysql.jdbc.Driver.class.getName())`. (Not recommended).
7. This is not how you make singletons; if 2 threads invoke the `getStatement` method at the same time, 2 connections and 2 statements are likely created, and an arbitrary one 'wins' and ends up setting the fields. You can use double locking if you must. However, that is irrelevant: You cannot have a 'singleton connection'; connections do not work that way. Connections don't work in multithreaded environments, either. Each needs its own connection. Use a connection pooler, see  point 9.
8. Using raw JDBC to talk to DBs is not recommended. You should probably use something like [JDBI](http://jdbi.org/).
9. If you want to optimize away from creating a connection every time you need one (I would recommend when you start out that you don't do this; anytime you need to talk to the DB, make a connection, do your thing, and close it again. If you do a lot of DB work this might get inefficient, but wait for this inefficiency to actually show; modern servers and DBs can handle quite a bit of connection traffic as is) – use a pooler such as [HikariCP](https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP).
10. The proper name of this class would be `JdbcConnection`. De-capitalize acronyms (it is `DvdPlayer`. not `DVDPlayer`, in java convention).

Answer (score 1):

The `stmt` variable you are returning is always `null`. You probably forgot the following statement somewhere:

```
stmt = Singleton_stmt;
```

Even after fixing that issue, using a single `Statement` instance is wrong.

The Javadoc of `Statement` says:

> if the reading of one ResultSet object is interleaved with the reading of another, each must have been generated by different Statement objects.

This means that if your code may execute SQL statements concurrently, you cannot use a single `Statement` instance.